# Responsive table with different layout options

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

We are trying to display data in a grid on my web page which needs to be responsive. We would like to have two breakpoints to cater for the form factors that we are targeting.

Here is the layout that we are using

http://jsbin.com/sinexesaxe/1/

Is there a way to achieve this using CSS?
This should be compatible with IE8 also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using actual tables, EMULATE them by applying classes, such as:

```
<div class="table">
<div class="tr">
<div class="td">
Content...
</div>
```

etc..., then set the "display" property in **CSS** to their HTML counterparts:

```
.table{
display:table;
}
.tr{
display:table-row;
}
.td{
display:table-cell;
}
```

This way, you can deal with the table differently when needed, see my example:
http://www.grafik-wunder.de/klafo/?action=userlist

or this Fiddle (more tidy and to the point):
http://jsfiddle.net/svArtist/dnbduwcj/

you could add IDs in HTML (or PHP if the tables are created dynamically) and apply an :after selector to create a break

Comment: I still have one problem.. Description field which is the third column need to be moved to fifth column for small screens. How can I do that?

Comment: okay.. I was able to get this using display:table-footer-group for that column.

Comment: This sounds like another job for Javascript/JQuery: i would suggest append()  [link](http://api.jquery.com/append/) to move the column to the end, and change its CSS class to something fitting your purpose (with a `display:block` rule etc), OR, get the contents (JQuery .html()), remove the <div> used to create the third cell, and append a new object with the new class already in it. (sorry I don't have time for a fiddle right now) - good luck!